# iOS - Security Framework had been added. But is it being used?

Tags: ios, security, code-analysis, ios-frameworks

I'm looking at the source code for an application. Underneath Frameworks I see that Security Framework (Security.Framework) has been added, but I can't tell if it's being used.

What's an effective way of checking whether the Framework is being used? In other words, how can I tell if the developer is properly using the framework? I'm not too familiar with the framework. It looks as though the developer needs to actually utilize the framework, and that it doesn't provide any protection just because it's installed. Please, correct me if I'm wrong.

The documentation I've been looking through hasn't been very helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Remove the framework and see what linker errors you get when you build. That will tell you what symbols were being used giving you something to search for. Of course other libraries could be using the Security framework so this isn't a perfect solution.

Comment: You could, of course, just look for the header import with a global project search (⇧+⌘+F)

Comment: @CodaFi Doh! That's too simple. :)  Yes, a search for `#import <Security` would help find files using APIs from the framework.